# Low-resolution version of logo too vague

Tags: feature-request, design

While the new logo looks great at higher resolutions (e.g. in the title just under the navigation bar), it's really 'vague' (sorry, I don't know how to phrase it) in e.g. the Hot Network Questions list and the hamburger menu:

[image] [image]

For starters, the black background should probably be removed; also, a lower number of lines probably suffices to convey the idea that it's a fingerprint.

Comment: For one I have no idea of the relation between a fingerprint and AI

Comment: @DuttaA I was wondering the same thing!  (Not that I'm complaining. Certainly less menacing than the HAL 2000 eye;)

Answer (score 1):

This would indeed seem to be problematic.  Although the icon is unique, it does appear to be a muddy blob of color at the smaller size.  Aside from the aesthetic, it's difficult to make an association to a stack when the image is not clear.